# How to pass parameter to FormsOf function in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My problem is similar to this one:
I'm having trouble using paramaters in a full-text search with FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL:
This query does not return anything.

```
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchWord = 'tax'
SELECT listing_id, RANK, name, address, city, zip, heading, phone 
FROM listings a, 
FREETEXTTABLE(listings, *, 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, @SearchWord')
WHERE [KEY] = a.listing_id
ORDER BY RANK DESC, name
```

but this one works OK

```
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(4000)
SET @SearchWord = 'tax'
SELECT listing_id, RANK, name, address, city, zip, heading, phone 
FROM listings a, 
FREETEXTTABLE(listings, *, 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, tax')
WHERE [KEY] = a.listing_id
ORDER BY RANK DESC, name
```

I found this question [here](http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL--HOW-do-you-use-paramaters-with-FormsOf-INFLECTIONAL-xxx--B0qhG78Q.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for "@SearchWord" instead of "tax" !

Try this query:

```
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(max)
SET @SearchWord = 'tax'

DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(max)
SET @SearchString = 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, "' + @SearchWord + '")'

SELECT listing_id, RANK, name, address, city, zip, heading, phone 
FROM listings a, 
FREETEXTTABLE(listings, *, @SearchString)
WHERE [KEY] = a.listing_id
ORDER BY RANK DESC, name
```

Comment: Any idea how susceptible/immune this would be to SQL injection attacks? As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176440/parameters-in-the-formsof-function-and-sql-injection

Comment: @Andrew M: Wether this code is open to injection depends on where @SearchWord comes from.  I think it's up to the programmer to know about SQL injection; it makes little sense to discuss it in each and every question about SQL

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant as a criticism, more an effort to understand the nature the parameter @SearchString being dynamically generated, and whether that offers the same protection of a more simple parametrized query. I'm also new to the syntax of the FormsOf function seeming being called from within a string.