# Parameters in the FormsOf function and SQL injection

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, sql-injection, formsof

Is the following SQL susceptible to SQL injection via the @SearchWord parameter?

I want to use parameters with the FormsOf function, but the only guide to doing so I've found is in this Stack Overflow question: [How to pass parameter to FormsOf function in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362220/how-to-pass-parameter-to-formsof-function-in-sql-server)

However the solution seems to be to use a bit of dynamic SQL, and I was wondering if that would be susceptible to SQL injection. What would happen in the following example if @searchWord contained a SQL injection type string? Is it not a problem because it's still within a parameter, passed as an argument to FREETEXTTABLE?

The solution given is:

```
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(max)
SET @SearchWord = 'tax'

DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(max)
SET @SearchString = 'FormsOf(INFLECTIONAL, "' + @SearchWord + '")'

SELECT listing_id, RANK, name, address, city, zip, heading, phone 
FROM listings a, 
FREETEXTTABLE(listings, *, @SearchString)
WHERE [KEY] = a.listing_id
ORDER BY RANK DESC, name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not susceptible. There's no dynamic SQL here (that would require either using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`), so there's no vector for SQL injection.

In order for a SQL injection vulnerability to exist, the user-supplied string (in this case `@SearchWord`) must actually be inserted directly into the text of the SQL statement.  Here, it's only being used to construct another string variable, which is subsequently used as a parameter to another SQL statement.

This statement **can**, however, **fail** if the user inputs an "invalid" search word, i.e. one containing single quotes, so you should probably still escape whatever value is passed to `@SearchWord`.  But it cannot be used to execute arbitrary SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I don't think the interpreter is simply pasting the value of `@SearchString` into the statement. It should parse `@SearchString` using the rules that FREETEXTTABLE expects--that's the way other parameters work.